Characteristic polynomial modulo $p$
Show that $A,A^p$ have same characteristic polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_p.$ Honestly, I don't have any idea how should I proceed. I thought maybe consider a field extension where the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ are, but I don't really know how to link them to the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A^p.$

Recall the definition of the characteristic polynomial, and use the fact that the $p$-th power operation over $\mathbb{F}_p$ commutes with both products and sums.

Your idea is correct. Additionally, (1) if $p_{A}(X) = (X - \lambda_{1})\cdots (X - \lambda_{n})$ (the characteristic polynomial $p_{A}$ is completely factorized) then $p_{f(A)}(X) = (X - f(\lambda_{1}))\cdots (X - f(\lambda_{n}))$ for any polynomial $f$ and (2) $a^{p} = a$ for every element $a$ in a field of characteristic $p$.

The characteristic polynomial is by definition $p_A=\det(xI-A)$. The matrix $xI-A$ belongs to $M_n(\mathbb{F_p}[x])$. Consider it as a matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{F_p}[\sqrt[p]{x}])$, where $\sqrt[p]{x}$ is the unique $p$-th root of $x$ in an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F_p}(x)$. Then you can write:
$p_{A^p}(x)=\det(xI-A^p)=\det((\sqrt[p]{x}I-A)^p)=\det(\sqrt[p]{x}I-A)^p=p_A(\sqrt[p]{x})^p=p_A(x)$
The last equality holds because for a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{F_p}[x]$ we have $f(x)^p=f(x^p)$, as it is very easy to check.
